# Proving that the equation $f(z) =z^n $ has exactly n solutions in |z|<1

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was asked in my analysis assignment and I am unable to solve it. i ahev no option except to post here.

> Suppose that f(z) is analytic for $|f(z)|\leq 1$ such that |f(z)|<1 for |z|=1 . Show that $f(z)=z^n$ has exactly n solutions in |z|<1.

I am really sorry but I will not be able to provide anything as attempt because I am completely cluless which result I should use.

So, I am asking you to just give hints. I would be working on details by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an easy consequence of Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: "i ahev no option except to post here." Don't you have the option of speaking to the teacher?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No actually due to covid classes are online and Teachers are not  discussing assignments as course itself is running behind course paln.

Comment: Strikes me as a lame excuse for not discussing questions with students. If your teacher has gone on record as refusing to discuss an assignment, it's time for you to escalate matters to the head of department.